# Where did the negative Compiz plugin go?

Tags: compiz

After upgrading to Quantal, I can't find the negative Compiz plugin. Why is that so? I found that plugin pretty useful for reading scorching-bright pages.

I see it's still listed on the [Compiz plugins page](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Neg).

Can someone help direct me on how to install the plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, while writing the question I found my own answer. The plugin is located in the [compiz-plugins [image: Install compiz-plugins]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins) package that can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

I don't know if this package stopped being a dependency to CCSM or something, because I don't remember having to install it before.